# как запустить сайт на golang?

Tags: веб-программирование, golang, websocket

Вопрос наигрупейший, но я что то не пойму , что нужно чтобы на сервере linux запустить сайт на golang на веб-сервере?
Просто установить golang на сервер и все будет работать.

СОбираюсь поднять вебсокеты на голанг, так запустить его как демона?

Нужно ли компилировать в исполняемые файлы linux?

Comment: Вопрос странный.  Компилируете статический бинарник, закидываете на сервер, запускаете.

Comment: хм, вёрстку html страниц сайта тоже в бинарник компилировать? Чтобы изменить вестку сайта нужно заново перекомпилировать?

Comment: Для компилирования внутрь есть известные инструменты типа [go-bindata](https://github.com/go-bindata/go-bindata), они поддерживают *debug*-режим, когда они смотрят на диск.

Comment: Для запуска демоном много различных вариантов -- от наколеночного screen до systemd и docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Для запуска веб-сервера -- вам не нужно ставить go на сервер -- это вам не python.

2) Вы должны написать сам сервер и скомпилировать для той целевой платформы, которая будет доступна.

3) У вас должно быть доменное имя (иначе непонятно как обращаться к вашему серверу)

4) Вы должны настроить сетевые компоненты ОС (файрволл, к примеру). Иначе к вашему серверу невозможно будет доставить запрос.

Comment: "иначе непонятно как обращаться к вашему серверу" - по IP-адресу очевидно

Comment: Ну, теоретически возможно, практически так мало кто делает.